# UpdateMode for DatePicker

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker, xamarin.ios

I want to change the update mode like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/picker-selection). This is my code:

```
this.datePicker.On<iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
```

The first part is marked as wrong `this.datePicker.On<iOS>()` and it is referencing an object in the xaml. On other places the same code is working fine. Don't know what's wrong here. The error message is:

> Returns the platform-specific instance of this DatePicker, on which a platform-specific method may be called.
>
> 'IPlatformElementConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'SetUpdateMode' and the best extension method overload 'Picker.SetUpdateMode(IPlatformElementConfiguration, UpdateMode)' requires a receiver of type 'IPlatformElementConfiguration'.

Any suggestion?

**Edit:**

It seems that the desired behavior (updateMode) is only available for `Picker` and not `DatePicker`. See [here](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/57/57859/bug.html) or [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97094/setupdatemode-whenfinished-is-only-set-for-picker). Is there a way to enable the feature also for `Datepicker`? How?

Comment: I guess the reason is simple DatePicker does not have this feature only Picker does!

Comment: Yeah I found that out. But is there a workaround? Put something of the code from the `Picker` into a custom renderer?

Comment: What you basically want in the datepicker is that the user selects a date and then presses the done button for that date  to be selected is that it?

Comment: Yes, only when the *done* button is pressed, the `DateSelected` event should be thrown. The default behavior is, that on every tiny scroll movement (before selecting done) the event is thrown.

Comment: After doing some research, I think updateMode for datePicker is not available so far.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT: That's correct, but is there a workaround or other solution, which has the same behavior? E.g. custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xamarin Forms 4.6 here. Inside your custom renderer use this code:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.NewElement != null && Control != null)
    {
        ...
        Element.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this new since XF 4.6?

Comment: I don't think so no. Not sure which version however.

Comment: Seems interesting, but currently I can‘t test that :-( Does this really work for `DatePicker`?

Comment: Do you think I would post an answer that I know doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, but often people don't fully read/understand the question and based on this write an answer, which is not what I asked for. But I think it's incredible that you posted this, because all other sayed it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm using it right this minute in my custom renderer ... it definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, UpdateMode is not available for Date picker.

And the workaround i found,is to create a custom calendar(which i did).Custom calendar looks tough to create,but is quite simple to implement(of basic functionalities) .
With only 1 month of experience in xamarin, i've created it.

You can check out the complete code here:

https://medium.com/@bhavyajoshi2793/custom-calendar-in-xamarin-for-android-ios-windows-578f1136daec?source=friends_link&sk=9b1c97e0021da2e48ec84b5b6d4ff8e4

Comment: You mean custom `DatePicker`? Don't know how much code that is, but perhaps you could add this to your answer here.

Comment: Updated. Please check out mentioned website

Comment: Also links to answers are bad and do not constitute real answers as the links are external and may change or be deleted.

Comment: Just wanted to be useful for someone, as i've gone through the same issue and have to create a custom calendar. Didn't know about your solution.Thanks btw. 
Any alternative to show complete code ?